Failure modes of fully drained NiMH batteries
If a NiMH battery is drained below a certain voltage, it may not hold a charge after standard recharging is attempted.
There is an Instructables.com set of instructions for possibly reviving NiMH batteries that are "dead" from overdischarge. The technique involves using a short heavy pulse of current. The instructions state:

Some batteries die when a short [develops] between the positive and negative terminals of the battery This happens a lot with NiCd batteries and can happen with other chemistries. The short is caused by a metalic dendrite crystal. The electric charge between the two terminals of the battery [encourages] dendrite formation.
by connecting a fully charged battery to the dead shorted battery you [will] get very high current flow through the dendrite. That will [cause] it to get hot and melt. [Hopefully] that breaks the short.

I have several questions regarding this.

Are there other common modes of failure for over-discharged NiMH batteries, besides dendrite formation?

If there are other common modes of failure besides dendrite formation, are there any non-destructive tests that can be made to determine whether the failure mode is dendrite formation or some other failure mode?

Are there other techniques that sometimes revive dead NiMH batteries besides the technique of applying a large but short current pulse to the battery?


